# c# - Parameter Error / Search Results Incomplete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I am trying to implement search in my MVC web application.  While my search results are correctly filtered based on text entry, my results will not filter based on date criteria / radio button selection.  My code is below.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string SearchString, int? daysBack)
    {

        var query = from t in db.Transactions
                    select t;

        // List of Transactions
        List<Transaction> SelectedTransactions = new List<Transaction>();

        ViewBag.NumberAllTransactions = db.Transactions.Count();

        if (SearchString == "" || SearchString == null)
        {
            // Display / add to view bag
            ViewBag.NumberSelectedTransactions = db.Transactions.ToList().Count;

            // Display list
            return View(db.Transactions.ToList());

        }
        else
        {
            // Select Transactions searched for
            SelectedTransactions = db.Transactions.Where(t => t.TransactionDescription.Contains(SearchString)).ToList();
            // Display / add to view bag
            ViewBag.NumberSelectedTransactions = SelectedTransactions.ToList().Count;
            // Sort list
            SelectedTransactions.OrderBy(t => t.TransactionDate).ThenBy(t => t.TransactionType).ThenBy(t => t.TransactionDescription);
            // Display list
        }

        // Transaction Date
        if (daysBack == 0)
        {
            // Display / add to view bag
            ViewBag.NumberSelectedTransactions = db.Transactions.ToList().Count;

            // Display list
            return View(db.Transactions.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            var oldestDate = (DateTime.Today).AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(daysBack) * -1);

            query = from t in db.Transactions
                    where t.TransactionDate >= oldestDate
                    select t;

        }

        List<Transaction> NewSelectedTransactions = query.ToList();

        ViewBag.NumberAllTransactions = db.Transactions.ToList().Count();
        ViewBag.NumberSelectedTransactions = SelectedTransactions.Count;


        return View(NewSelectedTransactions);
```

View:

```
<p class="form-group">
    Search: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { @class = "form-control" }) <br />

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
            <p>Date</p>
            <label class="form-check-label">
                @Html.RadioButton("daysBack", 15, new { @class = "form-check-input" }) Last 15 Days <br />
            </label>
            <br />
            <label class="form-check-label">
                @Html.RadioButton("daysBack", 30, new { @class = "form-check-input" }) Last 30 Days
            </label>
            <br />
            <label class="form-check-label">
                @Html.RadioButton("daysBack", 60, new { @class = "form-check-input" }) Last 60 Days
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Why is it that when I select a radio button to search, it doesn't lead to my search results being narrowed down to dates within the relevant range?

Comment: Does the page post back when you select the radio button? Do any results get displayed? What values are passed to the controller? You need to provide more information on the actual behavior vs the expected behavior.

Comment: Everything here looks right to me. Have you checked to see that daysBack is coming through properly? Have you checked to make sure that the results by TransactionDate are what you are expecting to get?

Comment: The page posts back, but doesn't seem to do anything with the selected radio button (so I am not sure if daysBack is being passed properly).  For example, when I select Last 15 Days, my results are still coming back with a transaction from 4/18/2017 (Valid) and a transaction from 2/24/2017 (Invalid).  These are currently the only two records in my database, but only the 4/18 record should be coming back when Last 15 is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an issue with my queries... I lacked a LINQ Where clause, which was preventing the date limiter from taking effect.